# If vlookup is between 2 dates, return earlier one

Tags: excel, date, vlookup

I have a list of dates when people submit that they want to sell something and I have a sell window which is every 2 weeks, where those sellers can actually sell.

I want to match the list with all the dates with the list of those selling windows (Selling Windows were on the 13.07. and the 27.07.), however the simple vlookup(using TRUE) returns me something like this:

seller
submitting | selling window (using vlookup from the seller window list)
13.07.2016 |     the corresponding selling window should be 13.07. here
14.07.2016 |    but 27.07. from here.
14.07.2016
14.07.2016
14.07.2016
18.07.2016
18.07.2016
20.07.2016
20.07.2016
20.07.2016
21.07.2016
21.07.2016
22.07.2016
25.07.2016  | However, vlookup returns 13.07. until here and
27.07.2016  | 27.07. as selling window only from this date onwards.
28.07.2016
28.07.2016

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I think you can use a combination of exact match and inexact match, but won't be able to answer until a bit later.

Comment: @ykjk did you even read my answer...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my idea.

If the exact match succeeds (e.g. for 13/7/16),take the result from the matching row of column B.

If the exact match fails (e.g. for 14/7/16), do an inexact match and take the result from the next row of column B.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,IFERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$5,0),MATCH(A2,B$2:$B$5,1)+1))
```

[image]

Just for completeness, here is a VLOOKUP formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$5,1,TRUE)+14*(A2>VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$5,1,TRUE))
```

and another formula using MOD

```
=IF(MOD(A2-$B$2,14),A2+14-MOD(A2-$B$2,14),A2)
```

but the last two assume a constant difference of 14 days between sell dates. The first formula is more flexible because it can allow for public holidays etc. if the sell dates are available as a list as stated in the question.

Comment: What a beautiful solution. Worked smooth like an oiled machine on my data! Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MATCH` function in conjunction with the `INDEX` function to lookup the values, this will allow you to benefit from the `match_type` parameter that forms part of the `MATCH` function.

Here's some information about the `match_type` parameter:

> Match type information
>
> - If match_type is 1 or omitted, MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in ascending order, for example: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE.
> - If match_type is 0, MATCH finds the first value that is exactly equal to lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument can be in any order.
> - If match_type is -1, MATCH finds the smallest value that is greater than or equal to lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in descending order, for example: TRUE, FALSE, Z-A, ...2, 1, 0, -1, -2, ..., and so on.

(Source: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

This means you can utilise the `-1` `match_type` so long as your `lookup_array` (selling windows) are placed in descending order!

The formula would look something like this:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$3,MATCH(A1,$C$2:$C$3,-1))
```

Where your selling windows are in `C2:C3`, your submitting dates are in column A and the formula is in column B, e.g:

```
  | A          | B          | C               |
  |------------+------------+-----------------|
 1| Submitting | Lookup     | Selling Windows |
  |------------+------------+-----------------|
 2| 13/07/2016 | 13/07/2016 | 27/07/2016      |
 3| 14/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 | 13/07/2016      |
 4| 15/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
 5| 16/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 | 
 6| 17/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
 7| 18/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
 8| 19/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
 9| 20/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
10| 21/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
11| 22/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
12| 23/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
13| 24/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
14| 25/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
15| 26/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
16| 27/07/2016 | 27/07/2016 |                 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are in date format - In your vlookup subtract 1 from the date. Your vlookup will then be 2 weeks early.

To correct this you can add 14 to the vlookup result.

=VLOOKUP(D4-1,$F$3:$F$6,1)+14

Where your list dates are in column D and your sale dates are in column F.

Comment: Sadly due to public holidays, the selling windows are not always exactly 14 days apart, otherwise good thought! ;)

Comment: In this case an Index Match should do it. =INDEX($F$3:$F$6,MATCH((D3-1),$F$3:$F$6,1)+1)